# Переменные PHP

Tags: php

Есть 2 php файла.
Нужно использовать перменную из первого файла во втором, но при этом чтоб сам первый файл во время выполнения второго не выполнялся.
Как добиться такого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сохраните переменную в сессии, [почитать тут](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php)

в первом файле

```
<?php
session_start()
$var="value";
$_SESSION['var']=$var;
```

во втором файле

```
<?php
session_start()
$var=$SESSION['var'] //теперь переменная $var равна 'value'
```

Comment: Не замучаетесь 1гиг инфы в сесию пихать?

Comment: а откуда там один гиг в переменной ? (не замучаетесь один гиг в переменную пихать?)

Answer (score 2):

перенести алгоритм получения этой самой "переменной" во второй файл - и если реализация сего алгоритма занимает весь первый файл то увы без "не выполнялся" не получиться

Может больше конкретики? ну там что это за задача) - возможно ее можно решить другими способами

Comment: первый файл загружает картинку из формы. собственно мне имя файла дальше нужно во втором файле - для записи в бд например. всё бы нечего но к первому файл прикручен ajax (вывод загруженной картинки на экран).

Comment: в сессию переменную запишите

Comment: Вообще практика показывает что данные о загруженном файле лучше сразу сохранять в таблицу БД. Проблем меньше, особенно если проект будет дальше развиваться.

----------

Из практики: Заказчик захотел ЧПУ имен файлов в транслите спустя полгода работы проекта, а реальные имена файлов равны md5sum

Answer (score 1):

Можно и в cookie сохранять:

```
 bool setcookie (string name [, string value [, int expire etc)
```

name - имя устанавливаемого cookie;
value - значение, хранящееся в cookie с именем $name;